# How do I write this proof formally?

Tags: proof-writing

How can I formally prove that

$$\max\{\lvert x+y\rvert _i \}   \leq \max\{ \lvert x_j \rvert \} + \max\{\lvert y_k \rvert \}$$

Where $x,y$ are the components of a $n$-vector with $1 \leq i,j,k \leq n$

It's obvious that if either $x$ or $y$ on the left side are negative the inequality is fulfilled with $\lt $ . But how do I prove that formally? Is a simple case analysis enough?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $m=\max\{|(x+y)_i|\}$. Then the maximium is achieved for some index, $\nu$ say. Then $$m=|(x+y)_\nu|\stackrel{(1)}=|x_\nu+y_\nu|\stackrel{(2)}\le |x_\nu|+|y_\nu|\stackrel{(3)}\le \max\{|x_j|\}+\max\{|y_k|\}$$
where $(1)$ follows from the definition of vector addition, $(2)$ is the triangle inequality, and $(3)$ follows from the definition of maximum.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a formal proof.
Fix $1\leq i \leq n$, then it is always the case that 
$$
|x_i|\leq \max\{|x_j|\}.
$$
In particular, and using the triangle inequality, we have
$$
|x_i+y_i|\leq |x_i|+|y_i|\leq \max\{|x_j|\} + \max\{|y_k|\}.
$$
Since we pick an arbitrary $i$, the previous inequality is true for all $1\leq i \leq n$, hence also true for the $i$ giving the maximum. In other words,
$$
\max\{|x_i+y_i|\}\leq \max\{|x_j|\} + \max\{|y_k|\}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

For individual components, you have $|x+y|_i\le |x_i|+|y_i|, 1\le i\le n$, thus, from the definition $|x+y|_i\le \max_j|x_j|+\max_k|y_k|\forall i\implies \max_i|x+y|_i\le \max_j|x_j|+\max_k|y_k|$

Answer (score 0):

*max*{∣x+y∣<sub>*i*</sub>} ≤ *max*{∣x∣<sub>*i*</sub>} + *max*{∣y∣<sub>*i*</sub>}  by the triangle inequality

clearly,

*max*{∣x∣<sub>*i*</sub>} ≤ max{∣x∣<sub>*j*</sub>} (think about it)

*max*{∣y∣<sub>*i*</sub>} ≤ *max*{∣y∣<sub>*k*</sub>}

Therefore,

*max*{∣x+y∣<sub>*i*</sub>} ≤ *max*{∣x∣<sub>*j*</sub>} + *max*{∣y∣<sub>*k*</sub>}